# Beamer: handout/article mode - produce multiple copies of a frame with distinct overlay numbers

Tags: beamer, overlays, beamerarticle

Similar questions have been asked before, but I was unable to come up with a general purpose solution out of the answers provided.

First, here is a MWE:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=foo]\frametitle{My only frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[]
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \item Item \arabic{enumi}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\againframe{foo}
\againframe{foo}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen in the example, the challenge is in producing two snapshots of the evolution of the frame that is built. In the example, I try, but fail to produce two such snapshots: one at overlay 5 and another at (the final) overlay 10.

I am search for a solution that would make this possible, *without* modifying the overlay instructions within the frame. If this is not possible, I guess not only me, but others would be interested in a solution that uses *O(k)* modifications to the frame, where *k* is the number of snapshots (rather than *O(n)* work, where *n* is the total number of overlays.

It would be really nice to achieve this in both the `article` and the `handout` modes. I suspect that the former is more challenging.

I conjecture that this is not possible. If this is indeed the case, a definite answer will also be useful. At least one stop searching if this is the case, and perhaps beamer will offer this some day.

**Related previous questions**

- [How can I distribute beamer overlayareas in handout mode across multiple frames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/how-can-i-distribute-beamer-overlayareas-in-handout-mode-across-multiple-frames)
- [How to handle only overlays while printing a latex beamer notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120866/how-to-handle-only-overlays-while-printing-a-latex-beamer-notes)
- [Can I declare a different overlay specification in different beamer modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/can-i-declare-a-different-overlay-specification-in-different-beamer-modes)
- [Fading out slides in latex-beamer with the option "handout" produces empty slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128483/fading-out-slides-in-latex-beamer-with-the-option-handout-produces-empty-slide)
- [Selecting specific slides for handout?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154598/selecting-specific-slides-for-handout)

Comment: What do you mean by "overlay numbers"?

Comment: In presentation mode, there is no 5 or 10: your example yields 3 identical frames. I don't understand your requirements either because I don't understand the 'O(k)' and 'O(n)' or what exactly it ***is*** OK to need to specify.

Comment: Here is what I mean by "overlaynumber":

`\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do need to tell `beamer` what you want to appear in each frame of the `handout` version. You can use `\onslide` specifications to do this so that you do not need to modify the existing overlay specifications at all. (I'm not sure this is what you want - probably not.)

The following code modifies your MWE so that, in `presentation` mode, there would actually be 10 slides within the frame. These are then placed on slides 1 or 2 of the `handout`. This is a waste of code: if you only want to show slide 5 and slide 10, you do not need two `\againframe` but only one. But, anyway, with the two:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<1-| handout:0>[label=foo]{My only frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]% or whatever you like for presentation mode
      \onslide<1-| handout:1-2>
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \onslide<1-| handout:2>
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<0| handout:1>{foo}
  \againframe<0| handout:2>{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: slides 5 and 10 for handout]

More efficiently with only one repeat:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<1-| handout:1>[label=foo]{My only frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]% or whatever you like for presentation mode
      \onslide<1-| handout:1-2>
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \onslide<1-| handout:2>
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
      \item Item \arabic{enumi}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<0| handout:2>{foo}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure how this could apply to `article` mode since then there are no frames or slides.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to solve the same problem but - as you - failed to find a beamer-only solution. A possible workaround could be to extract the interesting frames from the 'slides' version of the presentation. In linux, the following works for me:

MWE (example of merge sort):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Merge Example}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{num}=[rectangle,draw,minimum size=1.65em]
    \tikzstyle{invis}=[rectangle,minimum size=1.65em,draw,color=gray!30]
    \tikzstyle{head}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1,minimum width=2em,node distance=3em]
    \tikzstyle{sorted}=[rectangle,draw,green,inner sep=0.3em,very thick]
     \node[head] (s) {S};
    \node<3->[num,right of=s] (s-1) { 5};
    \node<5->[num,right of=s-1] (s-2) { 6};
    \node<7->[num,right of=s-2] (s-3) { 7};
    \node<8->[num,right of=s-3] (s-4) { 9};
    \node<9->[num,right of=s-4] (s-5) { 19};
    \node[head,right of=s,node distance=14em,yshift=8ex] (s1) {S1};
    \node[head,right of=s,node distance=14em,yshift=-8ex] (s2) {S2};
    \node<-4>[num,right of=s1] (s1-1) {6};
    \node<5->[invis,right of=s1] (s1-1) {6};
    \node<-6>[num,right of=s1-1] (s1-2) {7};
    \node<7->[invis,right of=s1-1] (s1-2) {7};
    \node<-2>[num,right of=s2] (s2-1) {5};
    \node<3->[invis,right of=s2] (s2-1) {5};
    \node<-7>[num,right of=s2-1] (s2-2) {9};
    \node<8->[invis,right of=s2-1] (s2-2) {9};
    \node<-8>[num,right of=s2-2] (s2-3) {19};
    \node<9->[invis,right of=s2-2] (s2-3) {19};
    \draw<2>[latex-latex] (s1-1) edge[out=-90,in=90] (s2-1);
    \draw<4>[latex-latex] (s1-1) edge[out=-90,in=90] (s2-2);
    \draw<6>[latex-latex] (s1-2) edge[out=-90,in=90] (s2-2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the above example stored in the file `merge.tex`, the following commands will generate a 2-by-2 handout version with overlays 1,2,3,9:

```
pdflatex merge.tex
pdftk merge.pdf cat 1 2 3 9 output - | pdfnup --nup 2x2 --outfile merge-2x2.pdf
```

The obvious drawbacks are:

1. You would need to keep track of the actual page numbers in merge.pdf as
   they would shift if you insert/remove a frame and/or overlay before the
   interesting frame.
2. The generated 2-by-2 page would need to be spliced into the "vanilla"
   handout generated by the beamer handouts mode.

There might be ways to automate that, e.g., using Makefiles, but I haven't tried that yet.

Still, if you have a long enough animation and want to capture, e.g. the first, some intermediate, and last overlay, it might be acceptable.