# Beamer: repeat overlays in article mode

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I have a problem that is already addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224750/beamer-handout-article-mode-produce-multiple-copies-of-a-frame-with-distinct/225071#225071), but the part of the article mode isn't answered.

With help of overlay specifications in Beamer, one can generate several slides that share some stuff but differ in details. Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}<1-2|article:1>
    \frametitle{Foo}
    \begin{block}{Bar}
      \only<1|article:1>{Foobar}
      \only<2|article:2>{Barfoo}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This generates in presentation mode two slides with a block titled "Bar" with different content.
In article mode, I get only the first.

Now I want also in the article mode **two separate** blocks, one with the content "Foo" and one with the content "Bar". However, expanding the blocks overlay specification to `article:1-2` generates **one** block, and `\frameagain` is ignored in article mode.

How can I manage to get two blocks in the article mode without repeating the boilerplate code  (which is of course a lot more complex than a simple block in the real-world example).